# Scroll ListBox in terms of logical units with horizontal orientation

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scroll

In my application, I have the following ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="300">
                <!-- One ProgressBar and multiple TextBlocks -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This way, I have multiple items on the same line. If there are too many items for one line, the following items are sent to the next line.

The problem I am having is that ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" has no effect on the ListBox. The scroll down is still processing in terms of physical units. When I comment the ListBox.ItemsPanel part of the XAML, the scroll down is working properly, but only one item is displayed on each line...

So my question is the following: How to combine the scroll down in terms of logical units with a horizontal orientation of the items?

Thanks!